# Opening an email client on clicking a button

Tags: android, email

I am designing an app in which i need to open an email client on clicking a button. The email client should be opened with a pre-defined subject and 'to' address. Is there a way to attain this? Please provide me the solution and a code example if possible...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open Email program via Intents (but only an Email program)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312438/how-to-open-email-program-via-intents-but-only-an-email-program)

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54602382/413306) answer to get ONLY email clients

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Goes like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "some@email.address" });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

Alternatively, you could use [IntentFactory.getSendEmailIntent(String mailTo, String mailCC,
String subject, CharSequence body, File attachment)](https://github.com/yanchenko/droidparts/blob/master/droidparts/src/org/droidparts/util/intent/IntentFactory.java).

Comment: When i click the button its displaying that NO APPLCATIONS CAN PERFORM THIS ACTION.... Whats the solution???

Comment: This does not work reliably today - it will allow user to choose Facebook Messenger for example, instead of GMail. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15022153/1735603  (accepted answer in thread is wrong as well, beware)

Comment: This solution did not work for me in 2020 DEC. My working solution from official doc:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62877003/2155858

Answer (score 49):

To show only email clients use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:recipient@example.com?subject=" + Uri.encode(subject) + "&body=" + Uri.encode(body));
intent.setData(data);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you already chose default email client then it will launch it. Otherwise it will show a list of available email clients.

Comment: this works perfectly...i am astonished why it worked without permissions ?

Comment: @anshulkatta Because it does not perform any action requiring permissions. It just opens activity that can send email.

Comment: How do you encode the subject and body in case they contain characters that would break things?

Comment: @mixel After some testing, you need to do `URLEncoder.encode().replace("+", "%20")` otherwise the email will have pluses instead of spaces.

Comment: This is working fine.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a e-mail address on screen, you can just use in your xml, like this:

```
android:autoLink="email"
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok - now the above answer no longer works for me in year 2020. I found something mentioned on google official developer sites which worked for me.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Not working for me on Android 10. `EXTRA_SUBJECT` and `EXTRA_TEXT` are being ignored

Comment: For Android 10 and higher we need to add query in manifest to make `resolveActivity`  work as said in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65166064/10413998

Answer (score 1):

Prefer to use constants if available like for intent.type `ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN`

Kotlin:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intent.type = ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("emailId 1", "emailId 2"))
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject for email")
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Description for email")
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send Email"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open email client on emulator by configuring your email address with email inbuild with email. Then when call the intent will open and send mail.