# Android ACTION_SEND Intent not populating the To field

Tags: android

Im trying to send an email in Android on 2.1 and I have two problems.

1) firstly, to To field does not populate

2) the type message/rfc822 creates an error: "no applications can perform this action"

```
    Intent msg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    //Two types, rfc822 doesnt seem to work in the emulator
    msg.setType("text/plain");
    //msg.setType("message/rfc822");  

    //To:
    msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mEmailAddress);

    //Body:
    //msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");

    //Subject
    //msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");

    mActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(msg, "chooser title"));
```

I am running this code sample in the emulator

Thanks
Mark

Comment: I would have thought you need to set the `Intent` URI like "mailto:bob@example.com"?

Comment: hmmm, not according most of the samples that are out there...

Answer (score 9):

**To:** expects a string array:

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "some@example.com" });
```

And it will only run on a real device.
[An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734749/opening-an-email-client-on-clicking-a-button/2734847#2734847).

Comment: Ok, but it still doesnt show, and why wouldnt it run on an emulator?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem (on real device)!!

Answer (score 0):

Please use it like a String array

msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,  new String[] {mEmailAddress});