# Android - Share on Facebook, Twitter, Mail, ecc

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, share

I need to develop an app that has the share function. I have to share on Facebook, twitter, email and maybe other services.

How can I do this? There a library on the net? For the iOS development there were ShareKit, but for Android?

Thanks :)

Comment: It depends. You wanna share what? text? Image? or what?

Comment: i need to post click on image with share post that captures screen view and about that app link i need to share

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Paresh Mayani's answer is mostly correct. Simply use a Broadcast Intent to let the system and all the other apps choose in what way the content is going to be shared.

To share text use the following code:

```
String message = "Text I want to share.";
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Title of the dialog the system will open"));
```

Comment: @Janusz: Aren't there any way to directly get the Facebook sharing? I mean without not allowing the system to open the list of names(facebook,email,twitter,etc) for select the particular name

Comment: Yes you can integrate the Facebook SDK and use the sharing options directly. I wouldn't recommend it. It takes a lot of time for a result that is worse then this 5 lines.

Comment: what if I want to show only Twitter and Facebook when the share list opens because I don't support sharing other ways? How do I do it?

Comment: You don't do it. This would be throwing away stuff that is good for the user and costs you nothing. I can't see a very easy way to limit the list of apps that are used in the sharing process.

Comment: But, If I want to distinguish between Twitter and others to choose the text I want to share, how can it be done?

Comment: Many irrelevant apps show up in the list - which have nothing to do with sharing any text - how do i filter and show only meaningful ones (like sms, twitter, facebook, whatsapp and not some random e-commerce app)

Comment: when i sahre on gmail ok but how to share on whats app and remaining facebook and apps

Answer (score 37):

yes you can ... you just need to know the exact package name of the application:

- Facebook - **"com.facebook.katana"**
- Twitter - **"com.twitter.android"**
- Instagram - **"com.instagram.android"**
- Pinterest - **"com.pinterest"**

And you can create the intent like this

```
Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(application);
if (intent != null) {
     // The application exists
     Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
     shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     shareIntent.setPackage(application);

     shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title);
     shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, description);
     // Start the specific social application
     context.startActivity(shareIntent);
} else {
    // The application does not exist
    // Open GooglePlay or use the default system picker
}
```

Comment: It works, but for me it was missing the 
        shareIntent.setType("type/plain");

Comment: The type can be different for each application. I recommend to set it dynamically, maybe through another method.

Comment: Setting the type depends on what you want to share. The target application should also support that type. For this you need to test in a real environment. 
For example, some applications support images directly, while others don't.

Comment: just i want to share app store link through all available apps in device how to send link for gm,ail,whatsapp,facebook and other messaging,services

Answer (score 28):

I think you want to give Share button, clicking on which the suitable media/website option should be there to share with it. In Android, you need to create `createChooser` for the same.

Sharing Text:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is the text that will be shared.");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

Sharing binary objects (Images, videos etc.)

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

FYI, above code are referred from [Sharing content in Android using ACTION_SEND Intent](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent)

Comment: Your sharing text example is sharing an image

Comment: @PareshMayani Hello Can we share picture and text at same share Intents?

Comment: @PareshMayani. Must be "text/plain" and not "plain/text". Spent an hour to understand why it did not work for me.

Comment: Hello @PareshMayani is it possible that i can share a post on two social site on an single button click. For eg. there's a checkbox to select an account on which i want to share post, Now i have selected Facebook and Instagram and now on clicking a button the post should share on both Facebook as well as Instagram

Comment: @MashukKhan thanks for sharing R&D topic actually, I think you should do R&D on it and share findings here :P

Comment: @PareshMayani Yah sure I'm already doing some R&D for this. As i'll be able to find some good content i'll share it here

Answer (score 6):

Use this

```
Facebook - "com.facebook.katana"
Twitter - "com.twitter.android"
Instagram - "com.instagram.android"
Pinterest - "com.pinterest"



SharingToSocialMedia("com.facebook.katana")


public void SharingToSocialMedia(String application) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);

    boolean installed = checkAppInstall(application);
    if (installed) {
        intent.setPackage(application);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Installed application first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}


 private boolean checkAppInstall(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: @BugsHappen may be `appInstalledOrNot(application)` is http://stackoverflow.com/a/11392276/1293313

Comment: `appInstalledOrNot(application)` its means to check desire app is not install on your device or not...

Answer (score 4):

The ACTION_SEND will work correctly for all and it takes the Body of the text to wall in twitter, G mail.. but it fails For Face Book page... Its as known bug in the Facebook android SDK .. but still they haven't fixed it

Comment: down vote
 

The ACTION_SEND will work correctly for all and it takes the Body of the text to wall in twitter, G mail.. but it fails For Face Book page... Its as known bug in the Facebook android SDK .. but still they haven't fixed it

Comment: `ACTION_SEND` works well for Facebook and for Facebook Messenger. But it is worth while to prepare appropriate [OpenGraph meta-tags on the server](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/checklistserver-side) if you want the post of message display meaningful thumbnail and description. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images#19388031.

Answer (score 4):

This will help

1- First Define This Constants

```
 public static final String FACEBOOK_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.facebook.katana";
    public static final String TWITTER_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.twitter.android";
    public static final String INSTAGRAM_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.instagram.android";
    public static final String PINTEREST_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.pinterest";
    public static final String WHATS_PACKAGE_NAME =  "com.whatsapp";
```

2- Second Use This method

```
 public static void shareAppWithSocial(Context context, String application, String title, 
 String description) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setPackage(application);

        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, description);
        intent.setType("text/plain");

        try {
            // Start the specific social application
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            // The application does not exist
            Toast.makeText(context, "app have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the following code will help....

```
public void btnShareClick(View v) {
    // shareBtnFlag = 1;
    Dialog d = new Dialog(DrawAppActivity.this);
    d.requestWindowFeature(d.getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.setCancelable(true);

    d.setContentView(R.layout.sharing);

    final Button btnFacebook = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnFacebook);
    final Button btnEmail = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnEmail);

    btnEmail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (!btnEmail.isSelected()) {
                btnEmail.setSelected(true);
            } else {
                btnEmail.setSelected(false);
            }
            saveBtnFlag = 1;
            // Check if email id is available-------------
            AccountManager manager = AccountManager
                    .get(DrawAppActivity.this);
            Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
            Account account = CommonFunctions.getAccount(manager);
            if (account.name != null) {
                emailSendingTask eTask = new emailSendingTask();
                eTask.execute();
                if (CommonFunctions.createDirIfNotExists(getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.path)))

                {
                    tempImageSaving(
                            getResources().getString(R.string.path),
                            getCurrentImage());
                }

                Intent sendIntent;
                sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
                sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        new String[] { account.name });
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Drawing App");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check This Image");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        Uri.parse("file://" + tempPath.getPath()));

                List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager()
                        .queryIntentActivities(sendIntent,
                                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

                if (list.size() != 0) {

                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
                            "Send Email Using:"));

                }

                else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            DrawAppActivity.this);
                    confirm.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                    confirm.setMessage("No Email Sending App Available");
                    confirm.setPositiveButton("Set Account",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    confirm.show();
                }
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        DrawAppActivity.this);
                confirm.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                confirm.setMessage("No Email Account Available!");
                confirm.setPositiveButton("Set Account",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(
                                        Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(i);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                confirm.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                confirm.show();
            }
        }

    });

    btnFacebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (!btnFacebook.isSelected()) {
                btnFacebook.setSelected(true);
            } else {
                btnFacebook.setSelected(false);
            }
            saveBtnFlag = 1;
            // if (connection.isInternetOn()) {

            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                    android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                getCurrentImage();
                Intent i = new Intent(DrawAppActivity.this,
                        FaceBookAuthentication.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            else {
                ShowAlertMessage.showDialog(DrawAppActivity.this,
                        R.string.app_name, R.string.Sd_card,
                        R.string.button_retry);
            }
        }
    });
    d.show();

}
```

---

```
public void tempImageSaving(String tmpPath, byte[] image) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    tempfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), tmpPath);
    if (!tempfile.exists()) {
        tempfile.mkdirs();
    }

    tempPath = new File(tempfile.getPath(), "DrawApp" + rand.nextInt()
            + ".jpg");
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(tempPath.getPath());
        fos1.write(image);

        fos1.flush();
        fos1.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
            Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
}

public byte[] getCurrentImage() {

    Bitmap b = drawingSurface.getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

    byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    return byteArray;
}

private class emailSendingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DrawAppActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Saving..Please Wait..");
        // progressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String response = "";
        try {

            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                    android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

                response = "Yes";

            } else {
                ShowAlertMessage.showDialog(DrawAppActivity.this,
                        R.string.app_name, R.string.Sd_card,
                        R.string.button_retry);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result.contains("Yes")) {
            getCurrentImage();

        }
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

        progressDialog.cancel();
    }
}

private class ImageSavingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DrawAppActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Saving..Please Wait..");
        // progressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String response = "";
        try {

            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                    android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

                response = "Yes";

            } else {
                ShowAlertMessage.showDialog(DrawAppActivity.this,
                        R.string.app_name, R.string.Sd_card,
                        R.string.button_retry);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result.contains("Yes")) {
            getCurrentImage();

            if (CommonFunctions.createDirIfNotExists(getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.path)))

            {
                saveImageInSdCard(getResources().getString(R.string.path),
                        getCurrentImage());
            }
        }
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

        progressDialog.cancel();
    }
}
```

For facebook application use facebook SDK

Comment: Can you please complete the code? there are lots of variable and other functions missing

Answer (score 1):

The `ACTION_SEND` will only give you options for sending using GMail, YahooMail... etc(Any application installed on your phone, that can perform `ACTION_SEND`). If you want to share on Facebook or Twitter you will need to place custom buttons for each and use their own SDK such as [Facebook SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android) or [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) .

Comment: This is not correct...ACTION_SEND will bring up whatever is on the device. If Facebook and Twitter are on the device, then they will appear as a share option

Comment: whatever has registered for ACTION_SEND and it will create a chooser. it is not possible to use action_send to go straight to twitter of facebook. that is what i was saying.

Comment: However, in Android is more common to put a global Share button rather than only FB and Twitter ones. It only complicates things much more and also gives the user less chances to share something (a link, for example) in the way they want.

Comment: @Wakka and how do you handle then that Facebook in the dialog doesn't work? (Will not prefill with text). If you have to use Facebook SDK, you can't use the sharing dialog for any of the others.

Comment: @lxx sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

> **Create Choose Editable**

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My application name");
            String sAux = "\nLet me recommend you this application\n\n";
            sAux = sAux + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=the.package.id \n\n";
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "choose one"));
```

==============================================================

> **Create Choose Default**

```
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

=================================================================

> **Multi-Piece send**

Send multiple pieces of content

To share multiple pieces of content, use the ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE action together with a list of URIs pointing to the content. The MIME type varies according to the mix of content you're sharing. For example, if you share 3 JPEG images, the type is still `"image/jpeg"`. For a mixture of image types, it should be `"image/*"` to match an activity that handles any type of image. You should only use `"*/*"` if you're sharing out a wide variety of types. As previously stated, it's up to the receiving application to parse and process your data. Here's an example:

```
ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
imageUris.add(imageUri1); // Add your image URIs here
imageUris.add(imageUri2);

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to.."));
```

================================================================

> **Share With Facebook**

```
    ShareLinkContent shareLinkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setQuote("Application of social rating share with your friend")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://google.com"))
            .build();
    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        sd.show(shareLinkContent);
    }
```

==============================================================

> **Share With SMS**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.putExtra("Body", "Application of social rating share with your friend");
    intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(intent);
```

==============================================================

> **Share With Mail**

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "Address");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Application of social rating share with your friend");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email..."));
```

=============================================================

> **Share with WhatsApp**

```
    Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
    whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Application of social rating share with your friend");
    try {
        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).startActivity(whatsappIntent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "WhatsApp have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Dude, update it for all the social media :  Instagram, Linkedin, Twitter.. and  maybe others like Telegram, Wechat, Signal.

Answer (score 0):

This will let you share your app on whats app etc:

```
try
            { Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
              i.setType("text/plain");
              i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My application name");
              String sAux = "\nLet me recommend you this application\n\n";
              sAux = sAux + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Orion.Soft \n\n";
              i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);  
              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "choose one"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String message = "This is testing."
Intent shareText = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareText .setType("text/plain");
shareText .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareText , "Title of the dialog the system will open"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"your subject" );
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, ""));
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

**Share on Facebook**

```
private ShareDialog shareDialog;

shareDialog = new ShareDialog((AppCompatActivity) context);
shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
        Log.e("TAG","Facebook Share Success");
        logoutFacebook();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.e("TAG","Facebook Sharing Cancelled by User");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Log.e("TAG","Facebook Share Success: Error: " + error.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
});

if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setQuote("Content goes here")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("URL goes here"))
            .build();
    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
}

AndroidManifest.xml

<!-- Facebook Share -->
<provider
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{@string/facebook_app_id}"
    android:exported="true" />
<!-- Facebook Share -->

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5,6)' //Facebook Share
}
```

**Share on Twitter**

```
public void shareProductOnTwitter() {
    TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
            .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
            .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_api_key), getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_api_secret)))
            .debug(true)
            .build();
    Twitter.initialize(config);

    twitterAuthClient = new TwitterAuthClient();

    TwitterSession twitterSession = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();

    if (twitterSession == null) {
        twitterAuthClient.authorize(this, new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                TwitterSession twitterSession = result.data;
                shareOnTwitter();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                Log.e("TAG","Twitter Error while authorize user " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    } else {
        shareOnTwitter();
    }
}

private void shareOnTwitter() {
    StatusesService statusesService = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient().getStatusesService();
    Call<Tweet> tweetCall = statusesService.update("Content goes here", null, false, null, null, null, false, false, null);
    tweetCall.enqueue(new Callback<Tweet>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {
            Log.e("TAG","Twitter Share Success");
            logoutTwitter();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Log.e("TAG","Twitter Share Failed with Error: " + exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5,6)'

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the answer given [by Ionut Negru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20066218/626481),
From Android 11 don't forget to add

```
<queries>

 ....        
 <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
 <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b" />
 <package android:name="com.twitter.android" />
 <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />

 </queries>
```