# Share Image via android app using ACTION_SEND not working

Tags: android, facebook, image, share

I have bee following this

[Android - Share on Facebook, Twitter, Mail, ecc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814268/android-share-on-facebook-twitter-mail-ecc)

But I am unable to share image using action_send intent in android.Please see my code and guide me where I am wrong.

```
saveFileName = "";
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            Bitmap shareImage = null;
            shareImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(pc.getDrawingCache());
            OutputStream OS = null;
            File f1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Free Hand");
            if (f1.isDirectory() == false)
                new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/Free Hand").mkdir();
            SimpleDateFormat filename = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHmmss");
            java.util.Date today1 = new java.util.Date();
            saveFileName = filename.format(new java.sql.Timestamp(today1
                    .getTime())) +  ".png";
            if (saveFileName.length() == 0)
                saveFileName = "Free Hand";
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Free Hand", saveFileName);
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                shareImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);

                share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/Free Hand/"+saveFileName+".png"));
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Saved in " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/Free Hand" + "\nFile: " + saveFileName
                                + ".png", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v("Before image", "Before image");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
                Log.v("After image", "After image");
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
                saveFileName = "";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
            save = false;
```

The Logcat output I get is :

```
06-18 16:08:16.274: D/StatusBarPolicy(1378): [BRIGHTHY] 3. Show 3G indicator
06-18 16:08:17.791: W/ActivityManager(1378): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
06-18 16:08:17.804: W/ActivityManager(1378): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{454dabf8 com.facebook.katana/.ComposerActivity}
06-18 16:08:18.004: D/LGE_data(1463): LGE_Fast_Dormancy) new_state(2) i=(0) lastPDPstate=(2)
06-18 16:08:18.124: W/ResponseProcessCookies(15476): Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: datr=HgbfT5h8NEIMcQRt7EurBx16; expires=Wed, 18-Jun-2014 10:42:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly". Unable to parse expires attribute: Wed
06-18 16:08:18.644: D/ACRA(15476): #checkAndSendReports - finish
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.katana.ComposerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at com.facebook.katana.activity.media.Storage.a(Storage.java:140)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at com.facebook.katana.ComposerActivity.a(ComposerActivity.java:742)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at com.facebook.orca.activity.FbFragmentActivity.onCreate(FbFragmentActivity.java:48)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-18 16:08:18.684: E/AndroidRuntime(15476):    ... 11 more
06-18 16:08:18.714: W/ActivityManager(1378):   Force finishing activity com.facebook.katana/.ComposerActivity
06-18 16:08:19.214: W/ActivityManager(1378): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{454dabf8 com.facebook.katana/.ComposerActivity}
06-18 16:08:19.574: W/Flex(1378): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
06-18 16:08:19.574: W/Flex(1378): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
06-18 16:08:19.574: W/Flex(1378): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
06-18 16:08:19.574: W/Flex(1378): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
06-18 16:08:19.574: W/Flex(1378): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
06-18 16:08:19.574: D/StatusBarPolicy(1378): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 8
06-18 16:08:19.574: D/StatusBarPolicy(1378): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=40420 curHPLMN=40420
```

I am testing it on real device via USB debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use following code snippet :

```
try {
    File myFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/images/2.png");
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    String ext=myFile.getName().substring(myFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1);
    String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
    sharingIntent.setType(type);
    sharingIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM",Uri.fromFile(myFile));   
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
}
catch(Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
}
```

Comment: now it it showing up a dialog saying no application can perform this task

Comment: Firstly you should have a file in folder named images within your  SDCard, now get that image and den share it....It will work