# Share image is not working via ACTION.SEND

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I am sharing image on facebook using ACTION_SEND, but its not working .code is here

```
try {
                File myFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA/aa.jpg");
                MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                String ext = myFile.getName().substring(
                        myFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(
                        "android.intent.action.SEND");
                sharingIntent.setType(type);
                sharingIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM",
                        Uri.fromFile(myFile));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
                        "Share using"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

but it gives the error "Cannot upload"

I am using this link ("[Share Image via android app using ACTION_SEND not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081231/share-image-via-android-app-using-action-send-not-working)")

Comment: Try with .PNG image instead of .JPG image. Did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   try {
       File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/100MEDIA/aa.jpg");
       Intent sharingIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
       sharingIntent.setType(getMimeType(myFile.getPath()));
       sharingIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM",Uri.fromFile(myFile));
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
   } catch (Exception e) {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}

public String getMimeType(String filePath) {
   String type = null;
   String extension = getFileExtensionFromUrl(filePath);
   if (extension != null) {
       MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
       type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
   }
   return type;
}

public String getFileExtensionFromUrl(String url) {
    int dotPos = url.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (0 <= dotPos) {
        return (url.substring(dotPos + 1)).toLowerCase();
    }
    return "";
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you seen photo in share dialog ?

Comment: yup i have watch and also can write text but after pressing post button. it gives error in window

Comment: then it's working, i edit ans and put screen when i do share image as above code.

Comment: can i share image directly from server or first i have to save in sdcard..??