# how to automatically share to facebook or twitter, as I upload photos to my server application?

Tags: android, facebook, post, twitter, upload

I created an android application with its own server ... I made ​​a function to upload a photos to the server.

Then how to automatically share to Facebook or twitter, as I upload photos to my server application?

such as uploading photos on

> instagram

application with share to Facebook and twitter, where the photo will appear in the timeline Facebook or twitter.

apologize for my bad English ,, I hope someone can help me :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

To share content from device see this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814268/android-share-on-facebook-twitter-mail-ecc) and if you want to share content from the server after uploading then you have to write code on server.