# How to share text in twitter,facebook and email in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android application. My app contains a listview and when each listitem is clicked I am displaying its
related content in new activity. Now I kept a share button in the new activity and when that button is clicked I am displaying an alert with
fb,twitter and email icon. Now when I click on twitter the text in that page should be posted in twitter. Similarly for facebook and email. Please suggest me 
how to share text via social networking in android. I didnt work on sharing via social network android. Any suggestion or links may be helpful.

I have gone through examples in google but I didnt understood the flow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814268/android-share-on-facebook-twitter-mail-ecc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this and let user choose where he/she wants to share it

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hello");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I am sharing this");
try 
{
    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share..."));
} 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
{
    //Error
    return;
}
```

Comment: hi thank you...for facebook it is not showing the message on the wall...can we display default message on the facebook wall once it is opened?

Comment: Do you mean to say Facebook wall is not showing either of "Hello" and "I am sharing this"??? If yes please check your Facebook privacy setting (May be sharing mode is private). I didn't get you by saying "display default message on the Facebook wall once it is opened"

Comment: yes I mean to say on Facebook wall is not showing either of "Hello" and "I am sharing this"

Comment: While sharing of FB a dialog opens. At the bottom left there is a option to select where you want to share the content. At the bottom right there is a option to select the privacy of the content. Make sure both are set correctly. After all this if you still can't see the shared content open the wall on web browser and see if that is available there. Also, you might wana check your FB privacy setting to publish things on your wall. I can't think of anything else which could be causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`String message = "Text you want to share.";`
`Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);`
`shareIntent.setType("text/plain");`
`shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);`
`startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, your title here));`