# Facebook intent share not working?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I want to post some message on Facebook wall through Intent. But the code is not working

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"sub");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "fbshare");

    PackageManager pm = a.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
    for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList)
    {
        if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook"))
        {
            final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
            final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
            shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            shareIntent.setComponent(name);
            a.startActivity(shareIntent);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use  `FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature` instead of `Intent`?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814268/android-share-on-facebook-twitter-mail-ecc

Answer (score 1):

This will open facebook installed on your device to post content.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```