# Android MIME type for MMS (SMS) messages?

Tags: android, android-intent, send

The answer to [How to open Email program via Intents (but only an Email program)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312438/how-to-open-email-program-via-intents-but-only-an-email-program) shows how to open a chooser with ONLY email programs displayed by calling intent.setType("message/rfc822").

I would like to do the exact same thing, but choose MMS capable (or even just SMS) instead of email programs.

The end goal is to create a "share with" chooser that sends different content depending upon the form the message will take. (Since an email can be a LOT longer than a text or a tweet, and can contain an video attachment.)

Comment: I would not assume that every email program supports that MIME type.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is the MIME Type for MMS messages: "application/vnd.wap.mms-message"
This is the MIME Type for SMS messages: "vnd.android-dir/mms-sm"

Example:

Manifest.xml file:

```
   <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android-dir/mms-sms" />             
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".SMSReceiverService"/>
   <receiver android:name=".MMSReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is how I have used the MIME Types so far in my Android development.

Comment: Adding a data mimeType to the SMSReceiver does not seem to work.  I have left this off and my SMSReceiver is working fine.

Comment: Also I think the MIME Type you're looking for is `vnd.android-dir/mms-sms` (note the ending `s`)

Answer (score 1):

I found this [link to jTribe's blog](http://jtribe.blogspot.com/2008/12/sending-sms-using-android-intents.html).  Seems to have a functioning example of how to accomplish this, but frankly I can't find any documentation that corroborates that this is correct.  It does some weird things like setting the action to `ACTION_VIEW` (instead of `ACTION_SEND`) and then uses a String param, instead of a static variable in the `Intent` class... but here's the code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text"); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```