# How to properly handle this intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to have the user e-mail me when they click a button, and use this code to do so. While it works, it brings up a lot of other applications that cant handle e-mail, like Twitter and Facebook. What's missing?

```
String[] email = {"evan@example.com"};

Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,email);
context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application/4330419#4330419

Comment: Seems top be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312438/how-to-open-email-program-via-intents-but-only-an-email-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  emailIntent .setType("plain/text");
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"evan@example.com"});
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Subject");                 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail"));
```

Comment: the line that fixed it was changing      emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
 to      emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

Answer (score 0):

```
// start the activity
context.startActivity(sendIntent); 

// start the activity asking the user how to send the email
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

So you need to remove the last line.

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html