# Android: Get and Open Email and remove Bluetooth

Tags: android, email

i want to choice a app to send email:only email app to send my email,i have read  [How to open Email program via Intents (but only an Email program)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312438/how-to-open-email-program-via-intents-but-only-an-email-program)   i used intent.setType("message/rfc822") ,it very well,but Bluetooth and email give me to choice,i want to remove Bluetooth,and want to Leave only email.can you tell me how to send email not to show Bluetooth to give mo choice;

edit: if i used Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO); the bluetooth is remove but add  Text messages t0 give me choice.i also used

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body);
intent.setData(data);
startActivity(intent);
```

the bluetooth also remove  but also add  add  Text messages t0 give me choice.is there i way to only email app to send email?

Comment: I don't believe you can.

Comment: can you tell me why? thank you

Comment: By doing `intent.setType('message/rfc822')` you're inviting apps that handle the `message/rfc822` content-type to participate.