# How to add an attachment to an email?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this email sending code that does not show a chooser (good). How can I extend it to include a file attachment, without involving a chooser?

```
// Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312438
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
final Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:user@domain.com?subject=My Sugbject&body=");
intent.setData(data);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
Intent emailintent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailintent.setType("image/jpeg");
emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
"email body here"); 
emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] 
    {"test@gmail.com"}); 
emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
"Subject here"); 
String filName="file:///sdcard/photos/estdemo.jpg";
emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/"+ filName));
this.startActivity(emailintent);
```

Comment: Thanks Imran. Tried it but got a chooser with several options. My question was how to add an attachment without adding a chooser.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setType("image/jpg");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("photo.jpg"));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks Lucifer. Tried it but got a long chooser with Picasa, Messaging, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to sent a mail

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
String to[] = "asd@gmail.com";
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,filePath);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send email"));
```

Comment: Thanks Agarawl. Tried your suggestion but am still getting a chooser with GMail, Skype and Google Docs. (had to changes it a little bit to work, added '{}' to the to literal and made filePath a file URI).