# e-mail Intent not showing Exchange Mail (Outlook) as an option

Tags: android-intent

When I click a button, I am using the following code to start an e-mail and fill it with data from a database query.

The problem is, in the 'send mail...' dialog that pop's up when the button is click, it only offers the following options:

```
* Evernote - create note
* Gmail
* Skype
```

I need to send this via my work Microsoft Exchange server (my main e-mail client), but this is not offered (it is however, when I click on web hyperlinks or similar buttons in other applications it does):

```
private void sendEmail(String recipient, String subject, String message) { 
    try { 
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); 
        if (recipient != null)  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{recipient}); 
        if (subject != null)    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject); 
        if (message != null)    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message); 

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail...")); 

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { 
        // cannot send email for some reason 
    } 
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer in this post: [How to open Email program via Intents (but only an Email program)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312438/how-to-open-email-program-via-intents-but-only-an-email-program)

*Changing the MIME type is the answer, this is what I did in my app to change the same behavior. I used intent.setType("message/rfc822");*

Worked like a dream!

Comment: Hi, but changing setType to message/rfc822 gives call to skype also how to get gmail only or any default email clent

Answer (score 0):

When the screen pops up and you have the option to choose the application you need to send data, at that time select "Set Default Action". So, next time you use your app to send the email it will open the default application you selected