# Force a default browser on my android phone using a simple html shortcut page

Tags: android, jquery, html, api, android-intent

I created a simple html page that when you open it, it will automatically open your default mail application and fill in the To:, Subject: and clear the body of any default data.  This works fine on my desktop and my android phone, but I notice that on the phone it wants to default to the HTML Viewer application which does not fire the jquery in the file.  Then I notice it will not ask to use either chrome or the default browser.  I put firefox on my phone and it allowed me to set that as my default browser.  My question is can I put something in my code that will either allow me to choose a default browser (chrome or FF) or force a browser to be the default browser?  I read up a little on Android's API Intent filters but I am not sure if this is the right path and if I can actually accomplish this in my simple html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>EMAIL: Test</TITLE>
    <META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <META http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
    <META http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
    <META http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.location.href="mailto:test123@gmail.com?subject=Download&body=%20";
    }); // document.ready

</script>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What is wrong with using an `Intent` with `message/rfc822` mimetype?

Answer (score -1):

You can let user choose it via `Intent` as so:

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.setType("message/rfc822");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{ "recipient@example.com" });
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"INSERT SUBJECT HERE");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"INSERT BODY HERE");
try{
    Intent.createChooser( email, null );
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
    // WHATEVER
}
```

Letting the default app handle the email:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body);
intent.setData(data);
startActivity(intent);
```

Explanation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3312562/1894684

Comment: Where does this code reside?  Is all of this in my shortcut in the jquery? And is there a script I need to refer to?

Comment: Depends on how you are sending the email

Comment: I want to use my html page since i use it as a shortcut on my android device.

Comment: oh :/ well then I don't know. I cant actually wrap my head around what you are trying to do

Comment: Can i use jquery to call these intents?  I am not creating an app for the android.  Its a basic html page that i created on my pc that i put on my phone as a shortcut.  The problem is the device uses html viewer as the default program.  I want it to either default automatically to chrome or allow the user to choose the default.  But i want the shortcut to hold this intent code.

Comment: I have no idea about `jQuery`. I use `Java` :)