# How to show email app through intent

Tags: android

How to show mail apps through intent. I want to take user to only login screen not to compose email screen

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(resetEmail));
startActivity(intent);
```

The above code am using for open mail app through intent, but its not working.

Comment: is there a specific app you want to go to?

Comment: In All/most of the android device, gmail was already logged in.

Comment: no specific app.. it should be chooser@AndroidMechanic

Comment: @venkateshgowda Please try to google it first. You will get your specific answer on SO. Try to use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3312438/2078074). Hope it helps you.

Comment: what if user has yahoo account

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

```
    Intent mailer = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    mailer.setType("text/plain");
    mailer.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"targetMail@gmail.com"});
    mailer.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SomeSubject");
    mailer.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "SomeText");
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailer, "Send to...));
    } catch (Exception e) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

no.1

```
 Intent intent= getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.joyodream.jiji");
             startActivity(intent);
```

no.2

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.joyodream.jiji.main");
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.joyodream.jiji.main" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />               
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

**intent.setType("message/rfc822");**

this will show you all mail apps

Answer (score 0):

Example code:

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,message);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Refer to [this link for more info](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email)