# Android : Send feedback to default email

Tags: android, email

I've a feedback form and buttons for send and cancel. How can I make the feedback send responds to a default email when the send button is clicked? And how can I set a the default email. Is this possible? Please let me know. Thank you.

Here's is my java for the feedback form :

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Create custom dialog object
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                // Include dialog.xml file
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                // Set dialog title
                dialog.setTitle("Feedback"); 

                dialog.show();

                Button button1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Close dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                Button button2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);
                // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Close dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

[image: Feedback Form]

Comment: also you can see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312438/how-to-open-email-program-via-intents-but-only-an-email-program

Answer (score 2):

Open your email client programatically using a chooser:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "some@email.address" });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

To send email programatically without using chooser,you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a) link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following snippet:

```
     private void sendEmail(String email) {

                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);

                    String aEmailList[] = {email};
                    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
                    String feedback_msg = getString(R.string.feedback_msg);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<i><font color='your color'>" + feedback_msg + "</font></i>"));
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.feedback_msg));

                    PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
                    boolean isIntentSafe = emailIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null;
                    if (isIntentSafe) {
                        startActivity(emailIntent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.email_app_not_installed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } 
   }
```

Comment: I'm kind of lost. Where should I add this snippet? @Ram

Comment: Call this method with email Id as a param in on click of send button