# How can I start Android's email application (com.android.email)?

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I start Android's email application (com.android.email)?

Comment: This post looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734749/opening-an-email-client-on-clicking-a-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is useful for u to open the email application.

```
Intent mailClient = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mailClient.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivity");
mailClient.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(mailClient);
```

Comment: The package on my tablet is different:
    `mailClient.setClassName("com.sec.android.app.latin.launcher.email", "com.sec.android.app.latin.launcher.email.Launcher");`

Answer (score 2):

you can start through intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "your@email.com" });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "YOUR SUBJECT");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR MAIL BODY");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

Comment: I'm trying to open "Email" app not some email app =D

Comment: I think the question was asking how to open the app (view the inbox)

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to launch a package this should be the solution you are looking for:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following intent to start email application on android device:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

String[] recipients = new String[]{"a@email.com", "",};

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is email's message");

emailIntent.setType("text/plain");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```