# Open a Email Client alone (Not other sharing apps) with File Attachment in Android

Tags: java, android, email, xamarin

I have a requirement to open the email client with text file attachment.  I followed the answer in SO link, however it opens all other sharing apps and let user to choose Email client before.  I need to open default email client with attachment

[Opening an email client on clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734749/opening-an-email-client-on-clicking-a-button)

**Tried out 1**: I tried to change

```
intent.setType("plain/text");
```

to

```
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
```

**Tried out 2** : I included the following line

```
 string fileLocation;
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
 intent.SetType("message/rfc822");
 intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("mailto:" + "support@yyy.com"));
 intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, "Help");
 string messageBody = "sdfasfasdf";
 intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, Android.Text.Html.FromHtml(messageBody));
 Java.IO.File emailAttachment = new Java.IO.File(fileLocation);
 intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(emailAttachment));
 Intent mailer = Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "");
 context.StartActivity(mailer);
```

This solution opens the email client alone perfectly.  However, the attachment was not included.

Any other ideas!!

Comment: Where/how are you supplying an attachment? Show full code please.

Comment: I have edited and added full code..This is xamarin android.  Dont get confused where the code is similar to native andorid

Comment: That code does not compile. Not a single line. Please only post code that compiles.

Comment: Oh sorry... is that xamarin code? Then i said nothing... Sorry.

Comment: There is nothing with Xamarin. If you could solve the issue in native android, I can convert it to Xamarin easily

Comment: Nothing with xamarin? You have a xamarin tag.Then remove it.  And your code does not compile.